# How to compress every file in a directory into its own compressed file (files not in current directory)

Tags: scripting, tar, compression

If the location `DATA/AAA/INPUT` contains *n* files (the file names are random job names), I need to create tar files for all the *n* files in the `DATA/AAA/OUTPUT` location with a common name format.

So, if there were *n* files in `INPUT`, then the `OUTPUT` location should have *n* tar files in the format:

`log1.tar`, `log2.tar`, ... , `logn.tar`.

FILE_NAME_PREFIX=EDWETLLogs
today=`date '+%d_%m_%Y'`;
count=`ls -lrt /DEVL3/EW/EWD1/DATA/AED/INPUT | wc -l`
i=1
while [[ $i -le $count ]]
do
if [ $i -le 9 ];then

```
    tar czvf /DEVL3/EW/EWD1/DATA/AED/OUTPUT/${FILE_NAME_PREFIX}_${today}_0${i}.tar.gz /DEVL3/EW/EWD1/DATA/AED/INPUT        
  else
   
    tar czvf /DEVL3/EW/EWD1/DATA/AED/OUTPUT/${FILE_NAME_PREFIX}_${today}_${i}.tar.gz /DEVL3/EW/EWD1/DATA/AED/INPUT 

    
  fi
 ((i=i+1))
```

done

i tried the above code but the output it produces is
it compresses all files into one single tar file

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please post your attempts and explain why they don't do as you expect.

Comment: Why create `tar` archives of each file? Can't you just compress them with `gzip` or some other compressor tool?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd /path/to/DATA/AAA/INPUT
$ for file in *; do tar cf ../OUTPUT/"${file}".tar "${file}"; done
```